Can't resolve any DNS addresses, resolveconf is not installed (and can't be installed)
I just updated to 24.04. Ever since, my machine hasn't been able to resolve any DNS names, making it impossible to update or install any packages.
I've followed numerous forum posts saying to edit resolv.conf, but my file (symbolic link) points to a location in a directory that doesn't exist (../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf). I don't have the resolvconf package installed and I can't install it due to the ongoing issue. I've also stopped and disabled NetworkManager then restarted/enabled it to no effect.
Everyone I've seen encounter this problem solves it by using tools like resolvconf, but I for some reason don't have access to any of them and can't figure out how to get them. I'm running ubuntu on a laptop over WiFi connection.
ip a output:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp58s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:b6:d0:ef:6c:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.201/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp58s0
       valid_lft 42702sec preferred_lft 42702sec
    inet6 2603:7080:8e3a:8902::1c9b/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604303sec preferred_lft 604303sec
    inet6 fd00:9491:7fc3:b5f8::1c9b/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604303sec preferred_lft 604303sec
    inet6 2603:7080:8e3a:8902:af17:8baa:5232:da2d/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604303sec preferred_lft 85374sec
    inet6 2603:7080:8e3a:8902:e2fc:6c92:8de0:ebf/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604544sec preferred_lft 604544sec
    inet6 fd00:9491:7fc3:b5f8:5ea7:41c5:3642:973f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604303sec preferred_lft 85374sec
    inet6 fd00:9491:7fc3:b5f8:2a38:8896:de03:8d4d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604544sec preferred_lft 604544sec
    inet6 fe80::2873:cef:157f:5a57/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

resolvectl status output:
Command 'resolvectl' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install systemd-resolved  # version 253.5-1ubuntu7, or
sudo apt install systemd           # version 253.5-1ubuntu7

cat /etc/netplan/* output:
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-23531f6d-4afa-4d4e-b910-600d048bcaf3:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "wlp58s0"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: ""
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "23531f6d-4afa-4d4e-b910-600d048bcaf3"
            name: ""
            passthrough:
              wifi-security.auth-alg: "open"
              ipv6.addr-gen-mode: "default"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "23531f6d-4afa-4d4e-b910-600d048bcaf3"
        name: ""
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-32c63030-6242-4279-9e5a-a055eeb8d8d9:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "wlp58s0"
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "14mn":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password:
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "32c63030-6242-4279-9e5a-a055eeb8d8d9"
            name: ""
            passthrough:
              connection.timestamp: "1705184110"
              wifi-security.auth-alg: "open"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "32c63030-6242-4279-9e5a-a055eeb8d8d9"
        name: ""
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-89d0b746-b032-4da0-924f-55ce8ad62274:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: ""
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: ""
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "89d0b746-b032-4da0-924f-55ce8ad62274"
            name: ""
            passthrough:
              connection.timestamp: "1710898792"
              wifi-security.auth-alg: "open"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "89d0b746-b032-4da0-924f-55ce8ad62274"
        name: ""
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    NM-8d26504f-2bd6-4d6a-ad06-0969c5838eb6:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: ""
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      ipv6-address-generation: "stable-privacy"
      access-points:
        "":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: ""
          networkmanager:
            uuid: "8d26504f-2bd6-4d6a-ad06-0969c5838eb6"
            name: ""
            passthrough:
              connection.timestamp: "1704069031"
              wifi-security.auth-alg: "open"
              ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
              proxy._: ""
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "8d26504f-2bd6-4d6a-ad06-0969c5838eb6"
        name: ""

I took out some wifi information for security reasons.

Since you mention Network Manager I’m assuming this is a Desktop install and not a Server. Please confirm. Meanwhile, edit/update your question with the output of ip a and resolvectl status and cat /etc/netplan/*. Add a screenshot of your network settings. Do not edit /etc/resolv.conf . Do not edit /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. Do not install resolvconf.

You're correct, this is a desktop install. I made the appropriate edits to the question as well

It should be /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf instead of ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf.
Also, consider a new systemd approach to supply additional DNS information to systemd-resolved instead of editing stub-resolv.conf directly: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html
TL;DR You can add a new conf file
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/<some name>.conf
with a content like
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8


It’s generally not a good idea to upgrade until the first point release, 24.0.1, which will be in August. And since you’ve upgraded, you’ve run into an issue that I’ve heard about where sysyemd-resolved is removed.
Therefore, to fix your problem, install with the following command:
sudo apt install systemd-resolved

This will re-install the resolver and should fix your problem.

I think this would work, however since I can't resolve dns names, I can't install the package as my computer will not connect to the necessary servers.
